# How to run queue:work command in laravel task scheduler?

Tags: php, laravel, queue, task

I have been searching a lot for a solution until I just gave up...
I want to run `php artisan queue:work --stop-when-empty` command every minute in Laravel task scheduler.

I have tried this

```
$schedule->command('queue:work --stop-when-empty')->everyMinute()->runInBackground();
```

but that doesn't seem to work at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not supposed to run the queue in the scheduler.

The queue should always be up and running (using a process manager, like Supervisor) and pick jobs when they are dispatched (dispatched in a scheduled task or somewhere else, it doesn't matter).

Here is the documentation on this topic: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#supervisor-configuration

Comment: Thanks, that helped!